# Modify padding-bottom on p

Tags: css, wordpress, dynamic, padding, paragraph

I'm looking to dynamically modify the padding-bottom on p elements.

In a blog post where the content flows, for example, (paragraph)(paragraph)(image)(image)(paragraph), I would like 30px padding between (paragraph)(image) but only 15px padding between (paragraph)(paragraph).

The site is built on wordpress and would need to dynamically assign this spacing principle whenever the content is laid out in this way.

Any suggestions? Can it be done?  Thanks!

Comment: Please make it easier for that would like to help by showing your code and at least creating a fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is adjacent sibling selectors.

According to the CSS specification:

> Adjacent sibling selectors have the following syntax: E1 + E2, where
>   E2 is the subject of the selector. The selector matches if E1 and E2
>   share the same parent in the document tree and E1 immediately precedes
>   E2, ignoring non-element nodes (such as text nodes and comments).

See: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#adjacent-selectors

In your case you can use something like this:

```
p + p {
    padding-top: 15px;
}

p + img {
    padding-top: 30px;
}
```

Here is a full example: http://jsfiddle.net/6fyht2be/